# Loss function unchange in GAN model training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as n

# gene model define
class gene(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5],
                                           input_shape=(150,150,1))
        self.leak1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[4,4])
        self.leak3 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[4,4])
        self.leak4 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[4,4])
        self.leak5 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                                           kernel_size=[3,3])
        self.leak6 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                                           kernel_size=[3,3])
        self.leak7 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.conv8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                                           kernel_size=[3,3])
        self.leak8 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)

        self.deconv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64,
                                        kernel_size=[3,3])
        self.deleak1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add1 = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64,
                                        kernel_size=[3,3])
        self.deleak2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add2 = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,
                                        kernel_size=[3,3])
        self.deleak3 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add3 = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,
                                        kernel_size=[4,4])
        self.deleak4 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add4 = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,
                                        kernel_size=[4,4])
        self.deleak5 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add5 = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,
                                        kernel_size=[4,4])
        self.deleak6 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add6 = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,
                                        kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.deleak7 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.add7= tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.deconv8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128,
                                        kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.deleak8 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,
                                           activation=tf.nn.relu)
        self.add = tf.keras.layers.Add()


    def call(self,inputs):
        x1 = self.conv1(inputs)
        x1 = self.leak1(x1)
        x2 = self.conv2(x1)
        x2 = self.leak2(x2)
        x3 = self.conv3(x2)
        x3 = self.leak3(x3)
        x4 = self.conv4(x3)
        x4 = self.leak4(x4)
        x5 = self.conv5(x4)
        x5 = self.leak5(x5)
        x6 = self.conv6(x5)
        x6 = self.leak6(x6)
        x7 = self.conv7(x6)
        x7 = self.leak7(x7)
        x8 = self.conv8(x7)
        x8 = self.leak8(x8)
        y1 = self.deconv1(x8)
        y1 = self.deleak1(y1)
        y1 = self.add1([x7,y1])
        y2 = self.deconv2(y1)
        y2 = self.deleak2(y2)
        y2 = self.add2([x6,y2])
        y3 = self.deconv3(y2)
        y3 = self.deleak3(y3)
        y3 = self.add3([x5,y3])
        y4 = self.deconv4(y3)
        y4 = self.deleak4(y4)
        y4 = self.add4([x4,y4])
        y5 = self.deconv5(y4)
        y5 = self.deleak5(y5)
        y5 = self.add5([x3,y5])
        y6 = self.deconv6(y5)
        y6 = self.deleak6(y6)
        y6 = self.add6([x2,y6])
        y7 = self.deconv7(y6)
        y7 = self.deleak7(y7)
        y7 = self.add7([x1,y7])
        y8 = self.deconv8(y7)
        y8 = self.deleak8(y8)
        x = self.dense(y8)
        output = self.add([x,inputs])
        return output

class dis(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.con1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5],
                                           input_shape=(150,150,1))
        self.leak1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak3 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak4 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak5 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak6 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak7 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.con8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                                           kernel_size=[5,5])
        self.leak8 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha =0.4)
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,
                                         activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    def call(self,inputs):
        x = self.con1(inputs)
        x = self.leak1(x)
        x = self.con2(x)
        x = self.leak2(x)
        x = self.con3(x)
        x = self.leak3(x)
        x = self.con4(x)
        x = self.leak4(x)
        x = self.con5(x)
        x = self.leak5(x)
        x = self.con6(x)
        x = self.leak6(x)
        x = self.con7(x)
        x = self.leak7(x)
        x = self.con8(x)
        x = self.leak8(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, 0.5)
        output = self.dense1(x)
        return output





gene1 = gene()
dis1 = dis()
```

Here is model define

```
#imagegenerator 
num=0
learning_rate = 0.001
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_gene = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/',
    color_mode='grayscale',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode=None)
```

image generator

```
from undersample import undersample
for num in range(1000):
    for x in train_gene:
        x_u = []
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
            x_u.append(undersample(x[i,:,:,:],0.7))
        x_u = n.array(x_u)
        x_r = gene1(x_u)
        D_train = n.vstack((x,x_r)) 
        D_label = n.vstack((n.zeros((x.shape[0],1)),n.ones((x.shape[0],1))))
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            D = dis1(D_train)

            loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true=D_label,y_pred=D)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
            print("batch %d: D_loss %f" % (num, loss.numpy()))
        grads = tape.gradient(loss , dis1.variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(grads , dis1.variables))
        break
    for x in train_gene:
        x_u = []
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
            x_u.append(undersample(x[i,:,:,:],0.7))
        x_u = n.array(x_u)
        with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
            tape.watch(gene1.variables)
            D = dis1(gene1(x_u))
            loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true=n.zeros((x.shape[0],1)),y_pred=D)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
            print('batch %d: G_loss %f' % (num, loss.numpy()))
        grads = tape.gradient(loss , gene1.variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(grads , gene1.variables))
        break
```

train loss

I want to train a gan model that reconstruct undersample MRI image to a normal MRI image. But when I train the model with code above, I got D_loss/G_loss which be 7.666619/15.333239  and never change. Is this a code problem organ model train don't work like this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to feed generator noise and ask to generate MRI images. But, as far as I can see, you are feeding MRI images and then, asking it to check against MRI images.

You need noise in generator and when it comes out, you need to take mean_squared_error with the original image and then, you also need to take binary_crossentropy with the original label and the label you get with your discriminator.

After some epochs, you will see good images, given your model is sound.

When you start, the discriminator will have high accuracy, with time that should reduce. That is what you want.

https://towardsdatascience.com/gan-by-example-using-keras-on-tensorflow-backend-1a6d515a60d0

Comment: I input undersample mri image into the generator, and as your suggestion i add a MSE loss function to upgrade the generator but it seems to change nothing. It look like some code don't work well. I'm checking out. Thank you.